# Need the .NET PDF library to edit pdf info

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I need the 100% .NET library to edit PDF Info like Author, Title, Creator, Subject and Keywords. All PDF libraries I tried are unable to do this without completely resaving the hole PDF documents. So for huge files (>35MB) it takes too much time. I need only to update several text fields (see above) and I don't need to resave the entire document for this.

Is there any lib that can do it like image libraries change IPTC/EXIF fields (without changing the original image)?

Thanks for any help,
Murat

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322218/modifying-pdf-document-properties

Comment: Shay, thanks for the sample. I need to change the file metadata without creating the file duplicates, but in that sample I can only set the info to the NEW PDF file instead of the old one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTextSharp (hosted [here](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)) ?

Comment: Thanks RC, I've downloaded iTextSharp and played a bit with it. But unfortunately on the samples I found in the Internet the only way to change PDF metadata is - Open the file, set info and save to ANOTHER file, not to the same one. Do you have any ideas to set the properties on the file itself?

Comment: According to iTextSharp doc, I agree the only way is to "copy" the pdf and add the data, sorry.

Comment: Thanks in any way. I'll used it until PDF4NET team releases the new version of their product with such ability.