# ERROR "The document has no pages" when converting html pages to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

```
private void GeneratePDF(string path, string fileName, bool download, string text)
    {    
        var document = new Document();    
        try
        {    
            if (download)
            {    
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);    
            }    
            else
            {    
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + fileName, FileMode.Create));    
            }   

            // generates the grid first    
            StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

            document.Open();

            if (text.Length.Equals(0)) // export the text
            {    
                gvTransaction.DataBind();    
                using (StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter(strB))
                {    
                    using (HtmlTextWriter htWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter))
                    {    
                        gvTransaction.RenderControl(htWriter);    
                    }    
                }    
            }    
            else // export the grid
            {    
                strB.Append(text);    
            }

            // now read the Grid html one by one and add into the document object
            using (TextReader sReader = new StringReader(strB.ToString()))
            {    
                List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sReader, new StyleSheet());    
                foreach (IElement elm in list)
                {    
                    document.Add(elm);    
                }    
            }    
        }    
        catch (Exception ee)
        {    
            lblMessage.Text = ee.ToString();
        }    
        finally
        {    
            document.Close();    
        }    
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {    
    }    

    protected void GeneratePDFAndDownload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        string fileName = "pdfDocument" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf";

        GeneratePDF("", fileName, true, "");

        Response.Clear();    
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";    
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();    
    }
```

I got the following code but when i run, it says

> the document has no pages

Can someone help me as soon as possible? :(

Comment: Your question is very unclear.. What are you using to create pdfs? what have you tried? have you verified the html contents?

Comment: im using itextsharp. i just clicked the button onClick="GeneratePDFAndDownload" and it showed me " the document has no pages.

Comment: Typing "itextsharp document has no pages" into google returns [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278623/itextsharp-the-document-has-no-pages).

Comment: i dont understand why they say my document has no pages. im drained!!

Comment: Debug in the finally block just before closing the document if there is some content in the document or not. This possibly occurs when nothing is written to the document.

Comment: how to write something into the document?