# The Document has no pages with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp Library to build PDFs.
I'm trying to develop an application for certification (auto generator).
and every time I'm getting an error

> "The Document has no pages"

as exception.
here i build a PDF document

```
using (Document pdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 2, 2, 10, 10))
```

and saw some similar questions and the solution was there that the developer do not add next at all to the document.

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278623/itextsharp-the-document-has-no-pages)

here i add some text to the document and still getting that exception.

```
pdoc.Add(EnglishTable);
pdoc.Add(HebrewTable);
pdoc.Add(ArabicTable);
```

i build the tables in this way

```
PdfPTable HebrewTable = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPTable ArabicTable = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPTable EnglishTable = new PdfPTable(1);
```

setting the Direction

```
HebrewTable.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
ArabicTable.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
EnglishTable.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR;
```

and i take some text from excel file and add it to the tables.
and still getting that error.

Comment: Please share enough code to easily reproduce the issue. If I consider the code pieces you shared, it looks like you add no content to the tables, and empty tables add nothing to the document.

Comment: I echo @mkl's sentiments.  This question needs a full code sample to debug.  With the small set of snippets you have provided so far its impossible to tell why you are seeing the issue.

Comment: Thanks guys the code has worked perfectly, i don't what was the problem exacly.

Comment: I'm adding content to the tables data from excel file.